# Undefined behaviour due to this for-loop?

Tags: c

Is this undefined behaveiour because in the For loop the variable **i** has no  initial value?

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i;
int foo(int i)
{
    int ret = i;
    for(int i; i<4;i++){
        ret+=i;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
   printf("%d", i+foo(4));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer, yes it's ub. The unitialized `i` shadows the function argument version (which itself shadows the global version), as soon as it's read ub is invoked.

Comment: @RohanBari, `main()` returns 0.

Comment: @alexis: The code was edited.

Comment: thanks, now i get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main Answer

> Is this undefined behaveiour because in the For loop the variable i has no initial value?

Yes. C 2018 6.3.2.1 says that using the value of `i` in this situation has undefined behavior.

In more detail, `static int i;` defines an object `i` with static storage duration. Objects with static storage duration are “created” (in the C model of computing) when your program starts and are initialized with zero if no explicit initializer is given for them.

Then `int foo(int i)` defines a parameter `i` that is initialized when the function is called.

Then `for(int i; i<4;i++)` defines an object `i` that is not initialized. This `i` has automatic storage duration (which is the default for objects defined inside functions without a storage-class keyword like `static`). Due to a rule in the C standard, it is also relevant that your program never takes the address of this `i`, as with using the `&` operator on it. That rule is in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, and it talks about the process of getting the value of an object:

> … If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

In `i<4`, `i` is the *lvalue* that sentence speaks of, and the program evaluates it when starting the `for` loop. Because of the rule above, this evaluation has undefined behavior.

### Supplement

Suppose inside the `for` loop you had the simple statement `&i;`, which merely evaluates the address of `i` and does nothing with it. Then the rule cited above would not apply, because taking the address of an object prevents declaring it with `register`. In this case, another rule applies. 6.2.4 6 says uninitialized objects of automatic storage duration have *indeterminate* values:

> … The initial value of the object is indeterminate…

*Indeterminate* means an object may behave as though it has a different value each time it is used, or it can be a trap representation. Using a trap representation is another way to have undefined behavior, but many C implementations do not have trap representations for `int` objects these days. In this case, each time your program evaluates the `i<4` test in the `for` or the `i++` update or the `ret+=i` in the body, the C standard allows the program to behave as if `i` has a new value.

In this case, a variety of outcomes are allowed by the C standard. Some of them lead to undefined behavior in your program due to integer overflow. Others could lead to the function looping indefinitely or executing the loop as if `i` had been initialized to zero. Although the behavior is not formally undefined, it is not defined well enough to predict what the program will do.

Answer (score -1):

In the for loop scope `i` is a not initialized automatic storage variable which initilial value is indeterminate. There result of operation using this variable is ***undefined***

> —  The   value   of   an   object   with   automatic   storage
> duration   is   used   while   it   is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9,
> 6.8)

> 6.7.9 p10 If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not  initialized  explicitly,  its  value   is indeterminate.

[image: d]
[image]

Comment: This answer uses an image of text, which is disfavored, needlessly cites nonnormative text, and omits a criterion for the rule about when use of an uninitialized object has undefined behavior.

Comment: It's also very bright for those of us working at night, in dark mode.

Comment: @jwdonahue it puts some light on the issue

Comment: @EricPostpischil any use. Not only address as you wrote in the comment to the already deleted answer.

Comment: The nonnormative text in this answer is incomplete. The normative text in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 includes the condition that the object could not have been declared with `register`, meaning its address is not taken.

Comment: @EricPostpischil register storage class is distinct from auto, so how is it related to the question?

Comment: @0___________: “Could have been” is subjunctive.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If it was declared as `register` another storage duration rules apply. Not related to automatic storage duration.

Comment: @0___________: The rule in 6.3.2.1 2 says that if an object **does** have automatic storage duration but **could have been* declared `register`, because its address is never taken so that there is no barrier to changing the declaration from automatic to register, then the behavior is undefined. The reference to `register` is subjunctive, meaning it uses a hypothetical situation to express the rule. The rule itself applies to objects with automatic storage duration.